# Create structs tag? Or burn classes tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Are we okay with [classes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classes)?  If so, how come there's not a [structs](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structs)?  Would it be appropriate?  Should I create [structs](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structs), or would it be better to burn [classes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classes)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd prefer to just burn [classes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classes).  I feel that it's only used for questions with more than one class.  Before doing so, we should make sure that the existing questions are okay without the tag.

**Update:** [classes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classes) has been synonymized with [oop](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oop).

Comment: or merge into [tag:oop]?

Comment: @200_success: Or that

Comment: I'm with @200_success here. I think merging classes into oop makes a ton of sense.